# ¿Se pueden utilizar las variables de entorno para navegar entre los directorios con Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Estoy tratando de hacer un script en Python para instalar librerías en Python de manera automatizada por decirlo así.

Según lo que entendí en https://programacionpython80889555.wordpress.com/2018/11/27/instalacion-de-librerias-en-python-3-7-con-pip-install/ uno tiene que ir a `C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts` e Introducir la orden “pip install” seguido del nombre de la librería o módulo que queramos instalar. En este caso será matplotlib.

Entonces mi problema se origina a la hora de ir al directorio donde está guardado Python porque yo quiero utilizar la variable de entorno `%Appdata%` para poder saltarme por decirlo de alguna forma estas carpetas `C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\` que pueden variar en cada computadora, porque el usuario pude tener nombres diferentes y si utilizo la ruta completa mi script no me funcionara si el usuario no tiene ese nombre.

Yo he intentado con

```
import os
os.listdir("TMP")
```

o

```
 import os
    os.listdir("%Appdata%")
```

que TMP es una variable de entorno de Windows pero no me funciona al igual que `%Appdata%`.

y esto es lo que me arroja cuando lo ejecuto

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: 'TMP'
> ```

[image: Variables de entorno en windows]

Comment: `os.environ.get("TEMP")` te devolverá el nombre de la carpeta temporal, que después puedes pasarle a `os.listdir()` en tu ejemplo. Análogamente `os.environ.get("APPDATA")`, etc para cualquier otra variable de entorno (`os.environ` no es más que un diccionario python cuyas claves son las variables de entorno)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos a suponer que quieres usar un script para automatizar la instalación de librerías usando PIP desde PyPi, en este caso, lo normal es que quieras que se instalen en el mismo intérprete Python que ejecuta tu script.

Para que el procedimiento sea medianamente robusto y se adapte en lo posible a las peculiaridades de cada sistema, deberías tener en cuenta dos cosas:

- La ruta de instalación de Python o la localización del intérprete puede variar entre sistemas. Dentro de un mismo sistema operativo, no en todos los casos el usuario instala en el directorio por defecto, de hecho es bastante común (por lo que conseguir la ruta de `%Appdata%` no serviría de nada). Además existen múltiples variantes que causarían que instalaras los paquetes en interpretes equivocados, como el uso de entornos virtuales o simplemente que se tengan múltiples versiones de Python instaladas en el sistema.
- Por otro lado, podríamos simplemente invocar `pip` en la consola en un subproceso lanzado por el script, pero esto tiene también sus problemas. Para empezar, no siempre está `pip` agregado al PATH, además, de estarlo,  no es seguro que el `pip` lanzado sea el del interprete en el que han ejecutado el script.

En mi opinión, una opción más robusta es:

- Obtenemos la dirección del intérprete que ejecuta nuestro script con `sys.executable`.
- Teniendo la ruta, simplemente lanzamos `pip` como módulo. Para ello simplemente tenemos que hacer usar el módulo `subprocess`.

Una versión muy simplificada sería:

```
import subprocess
import sys


paquete = "matplotlib"

path = sys.executable
subprocess.run([path, "-m", "pip", "install", paquete])
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que si estamos haciendo esto para instalar las dependencias para un paquete propio que va a ser instalado, lo anterior es un camino incorrecto. Lo apropiado es [especificarlos en el `setup.py`](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/#install-requires)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar ejecutando un where pip para saber el path de pip y desde ahi ejecutar los comandos de instalación. Sería algo como:

```
import os
path = os.popen('where pip').read()
os.popen(path + ' install pandas').read()
```

Espero que sea de ayuda

Comment: Dentro de los parentesis remplazo lo que dice :'where pip' por el pip que necesito instalar en este caso  matplotlib
Deberia quedar asi?
import os
path = os.popen('matplotlib').read()
os.popen(path + ' install matplotlib').read()

Comment: Digamos que instalas un pip cada vez que lanzas el script? En teoría si tienes Python, este ya viene con su paquete de pip y no tienes que instalarlo de nuevo cada vez.